# Can't connect to mysql server (13) using php function

Tags: mysql, php

I opened every links google results had thrown to me in regards to this MySQL error. I have been spending hours to get  this to work..

I have a web server `(apache in centos installed in host B, and want to connect to a MySQL server in host A)` both hosts are in the same subnet.

I can access remote mysql using CLI
`mysql -u root -h <ip> -p`

but cannot connect to mysql using PHP function `mysql_connect()`

I have already disabled `SELINUX` and `system-config-firewall-tui`
and included below syntax in /etc/my.cnf

```
  [client]
  port =3306
  socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Some  solutions found in the web tells me to type in the `setbool` associated with selinux, but the thing is, SELINUX is already disabled.

the odd thing is, I can connect thru CLI, but not in php function

also, I have `php-mysql` in both hosts

---

Here is my main.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect('192.168.8.136','root','admin') or die (mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL server";

mysql_select_db("web") or die (mysql_error());
echo "Connected to Database";
?>
```

here is my /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld/log
id-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

selinux status

`SELinux status: disabled`

netstat -atn 
`tcp    0    0    0.0.0.0:3306    0.0.0.0:*     Listen`

error received at client where apache is hosted:

`[error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP warning: mysql_connect(); cant connect to mysql server (13) in /var/www/html/main.php on line 2`

Comment: 13 is an OS error code for permission denied. SELinux is disabled on host B, right ? just checking...

Comment: Are you sure that the IP that you connect from in php and the one from the command line are the same?

Comment: yes. i disabled SELINUX in host A and B just to be sure.

Comment: @NickW yes im very sure of it sir.

Comment: What does the log on the mysql server say? BTW, just an simple question, does the password you use have any non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: log shows `/usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections:` and yes, i have non-alphanumeric. user:root pass:admin

Comment: Cool, is there any further error information in server B's http error log?

Comment: on host B httpd error log: [error] [client 127.0.0.1] php warning: mysql_connect(): cant connect to mysql server on <ip> (13) in /var/www/html/main.php on line 3 (which is my mysql_connect() function line)

Comment: `sestatus` confirms that selinux is disabled?

Comment: setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1 try this and see if it works for you or not?

Comment: @NickW Selinux status: disabled

Comment: @AbhishekAmralkar setsebool: Selinux is disabled

Comment: can you post your main.php DB connection settings?

Comment: @AbhishekAmralkar i have included contents of main.php file

Comment: 13 is the OS error code for a **filesystem** permission denied.  Since PHP isn't telling you which file is the problem, I'd go straight for `strace` to figure it out.  Run this: `strace -e file -p <YOUR APACHE PID> 2>&1 | grep EACCES` and while that's running, try your script again.  Don't forget to replace `<YOUR APACHE PID>` with the actual PID of your Apache process.  If you have more than one, change your Apache config or run Apache with `-X`.  Or just run the script on the command line: `strace -e file php main.php`.

Comment: If the problem was with the IP or the port, mysql's error would say something like: "Can't connect to MySQL server on '<ip>'"

Comment: What does the IP traffic look like?  Is a connection attempt made, or does the permissions error occur before that?

Answer (score 8):

I could access from server B from command line mysql but I also could not connect my remote database via httpd - I know you say selinux was disabled on both sides, however in my situation, the httpd server side needed selinux

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db=1
```

to enable apache to connect to the remote database.

Comment: You saved my day again! I keep forgetting this stupid property

Comment: `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on` to enable it permanatly (can take 20 secs to complete)

Comment: This solution worked for me as well. In my case, ls -Z /var/www/html displayed a proper looking SELinux context, which is why I didn't think to use setsebool.

Answer (score 1):

do you have something like this in my.cnf ?

```
 bind-address            = 192.168.8.136
```

and in php do you have `safe_mode` or `apache mod_security` enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Check your MySQL root user "host" setting.  Perhaps try with anyhost, 192.168.8.%, localhost, or "www.domain.tld".   Probably a good idea to test with another user rather than using root...

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps and see if it changes anything:

1. Edit /etc/my.cnf and change `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to your Mysql server's ip.
2. Allow root user to connect from any host

`mysql>GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

However, allowing remote root access is highly not recommend, you should create a new user and give it only the permissions it needs on a certain database and use that user.

Update: did not notice the post date at first, but lets hope this helps someone someday.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code. I too got the answer.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

On CentOs 6, you can use the following (without -P)

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

Comment: A single command is not enough, better if you explain, what it does.

Comment: Check it out. [Can't connect to mysql with error 13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078205/php-cant-connect-to-mysql-with-error-13-but-command-line-can)

Comment: A single link is also not okay. As the years are going, link targets tend to disappear. And the SE (the company) needs qualified content to advice google to get more hits. But if you copy the essence of the link (some sentence is already enough) nobody will have any problem with that, and you will get upvotes.

Comment: Looks you won't really understand why I am talking, so here is a downvote, maybe it is enough good argument.

Answer (score -3):

Try this it should work

```
  <?php
  // Mysql settings
  $user   = "root";
  $password = "admin";
  $database = "IP";
  $host   = "yourhost";
  mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
  mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
  ?>
```

Comment: no, it didnt work. also made server restart after modifying. :(

Comment: Note that putting everything in variables is not going to make any difference on the call itself.